# Page jumps to the beginning after reload with open developer tools in firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

If I have the firefox developer tools opened and make a reload (F5) then the page jumps back to the beginning. When the developer tools are closed the jump does not happen. Scrolling down again and again is very annoying during development. Someone an idea how to prevent this? Firebug made it better and the dev tools of Chrome as well.

Comment: There is no option to deal with that (based on my knowledge), maybe you show report that as bug at [http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/](http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/)

Comment: I agree with that. I've made a bug report.
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1365209