# How to prevent Firefox Developer Tools to scroll page to top?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I've noticed that when I've the `Firefox Developer Tools` opened and I open any page (i.e. http://www.bbc.com/news) it scrolls the page to the top.

I've the 53.0.3 (64 bit). 32bit is the same.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Related: [Page jumps to the beginning after reload with open developer tools in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43974146)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is obviously a regression in the Firefox DevTools. So I've created [bug 1371050](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1371050) for it.

**Update:**

My bug report got marked as duplicate of [bug 1365209](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1365209).